# Using jQuery with Flask

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I have a problem using jQuery with Jinja2 + Flask-bootstrap and Flask framework. When I create:

```
<script>
     $('#commentButton').click(function() {
         alert('clicked');
     });
</script>
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I can see in Chrome dev tools, that jQuery library is received.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flask-Bootstrap includes jQuery at the end of your `body` tag. If you try to reference it earlier on the page you will receive this error.

The easiest way to make sure your code is placed after jQuery is to override the template tag.

```
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}

    <script>
        $('#commentButton').click(function() {
             alert('clicked');
         });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `$` isn't defined. May be jQuery's not included at all, but since you say it's included, most probably, it must have been renamed to another name, check for it.

Meanwhile try using `jQuery` in place of `$`, if it works, you can do `$ = jQuery`
which will pass a reference of `jQuery` to `$`, so you can use `$`